# Openshot-created videos have a slight greenish look

Tags: video

I encountered a strange issue in Openshot.

Every video I create has a slight greenish look. E.g. that means that pure white #ffffff becomes #f9fff9 in the preview and also in the video output. I am not using a filter or an effect.

I reinstalled Openshot, created different project with different images (including generated images that are pure white (checked with gimp)), different image types, different movie snippets ...
I watched the resulting movies in different players ...
and always #ffffff becomes #f9fff9.

I am using Openshot 1.4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I believe that one year ago this issue didn't occur.

I counldn't find anything about the problem on the net.

Answer (score 0):

If you're recording your video under fluorescent light, and weren't a year ago (or if the CFL bulbs or fluorescent tubes have been changed in that time) that could account for a green cast.  Film photographers have known for decades that the color spectrum of a "white" fluorescent lamp looks much less white to the spectral sensitivity of color film, and modern CCD and CMOS video sensors were engineered with similar spectral response to common color films of the 1980s and 1990s, so the video and stills they produced would have similar white balance in the same light.

Normally, white balance in software will correct this cast, but if your white balance has been inadvertently switched from "auto" or "fluorescent" to something else (say, "tungsten" or "daylight"), this might prevent the green cast of fluorescent light from being corrected.

BTW, because white LEDs are essentially fluorescents with the phosphor excited by a UV LED rather than a mercury discharge, they have similar spectral spikes to a tube or coil fluorescent, so the same thing can apply -- including a change from color corrected fluorescent lamps to "white" LED lamps.

Comment: That can't be the reason. The effect occurs regardless of the source. The video can only contain a generated empty white image (e.g. with gimp). #ffffff always becomes #f9fff9.

Comment: I believe it is an Openshot specific problem. I wanted to tag the question with **openshot** but I don't have the reputation to create a new tag.

Comment: You might want to add the part about a generated white turning green in Openshot to the question -- I agree, that seems pretty specific.  Good luck!